# MySql bug in php

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

I have used Joomla 2.5 and the administrator module manager displays this type of error.

```
Can't create/write to file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\#sql_490_0.MYD' (Errcode: 17)
```

can you please help me?

Comment: mysql problem entirely. You might not have any disk space, or some jacked permissions, obviously, lol

Comment: Well you could look up the error code first...

Comment: Ironically, you have titled it as 'MySql bug' but have not used a MySql tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-create.html

There are several reasons for this Error:

1. No disk space left
2. Antivirus or Microsoft Security Essential blocks the file
3. Running two instances of MySQL which are trying to write the same file
4. The user running MySQL has sufficient rights on this folder

**Solutions**

- Rename(delete) the file

  - Stop MySQL, rename the file, start MySQL.
- Add the folder to the Antivirus's/Microsoft Security Essential's exclude list
- Check in the taskmanager if there are two instances running of mysql(d).
- Running defrag
- Restart Computer/MySQL
- When you have PhpMyAdmin installed, select your database, scroll down and select and click "Repair".
- When the error occurred when using mysqldump add this parameter: --skip-lock-tables and --lock-tables=false

Other, similar questions on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Errcode:%2017%22&submit=search), [Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=mysql%20windows%20Can%27t%20create/write%20to%20file&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: Just where I was about to direct to!